# Google Maps and Firebase android plugins dependency collision

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

I am working on android applications where I am working on Google maps and Firebase. I am putting latest links in my gradle file but it is giving me an error with a red line on GoogleMaps gradle link.

Error:

> all gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixinb versions can lead to runtime crahes). Found versions 16.0.0, 15.0.4, 15.0.1. Examples include com.google.firbase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4

Gradle:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your play service dependency version equal and try  like bellow

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did above solution already, but I am getting "Cannot find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0" and also "Cannot find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"

Comment: Please remove classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0' from app-level gradel and add in Project level gradels dependancy section .

Comment: Okay I confuse because I seen with apply plugin.

Comment: Please try to update Play service library and Google repository from SDK manager (Tools menu-> SDK Manager ->SDK Tools)

Comment: That is the latest SDK version 49.

Comment: What is your build version?

Comment: Which build version you are asking?

Comment: Which you defined in your grdel, buildToolsVersion.

Comment: My Build tool version is: "26.0.2"

Comment: Cannot find dependency error, you cannot randomly add number for versions if they do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are two more dependencies that need to be added. All the dependencies that I wrote are mentioned below.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.1'
compile ' com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a perfect combination with Android SDK API 28
No error of any sort in gradle[image]

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Just post the code itself.